# How to invoke callback(JAVA) from pthread(C) in Android NDK

Tags: android, java-native-interface, pthreads, android-ndk

I want to invoke java method in pthread function.

But I faced:

```
JNI_ERROR: non-VM thread making JNI calls
```

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-ndk/FfQlfrKwwtw

Comment: Thanks but I think the link isn't what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your thread is not attached (or not propperly) to the VM.
When you make a call from Java to C++ trough the JNI bridge the pthread which your call is working on is attached to the vm.
Having threads in C++ that were called by JNI calls is volatile to say the least.
What you've probably done is make a new thread and tried to make a call from it without attaching it to the VM prior to making the call.
I think that to solve your problem you should just attach your thread to the VM.

So if you see the [Android Tips and tricks](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/jni.html) there is a section on the subject
If you go to the threads section you can see the part where they clearly say that :

> Until a thread is attached, it has no JNIEnv, and cannot make JNI
> calls.

you can find detailed steps to solve your problem in the provided link.

post your progress...

Comment: Thank you, I am going to do it. and post my progress.

Comment: The referenced doc wasn't very explicit in how to solve the problem. Here is another question that helped me attach my c++ thread to the JVM. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534304/android-jni-call-attachcurrentthread-without-detachcurrentthread